# how to use hide and show for dynamic values to hide values in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, show-hide

I want to hide and show the element values dynamically but the values are displayed both in hide and show (second image 2)

> Project [Stackbiltz URL](http://%20https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-toggle?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Do any one have any idea about that??

[image: show and hide]

[image]

Comment: Have u checked the modified answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let j of myObj;let i=index">
    <ion-col>
        <ion-label> {{j.name}}</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
        <button (click)="clickedIndex == i? clickedIndex = null : clickedIndex = i">
            <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown"  ></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
     <span [hidden]="clickedIndex != i">
        <span *ngFor="let value of j.prop">
          {{value.name}},
        </span>
    </span>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

**See [Working Stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-toggle-bkpsxd)**

Explaination: `clickedIndex` holds the index of the clicked row. Element values in span is shown only when `clickedIndex` is the index of that row. If you are clicking again, then `clickedIndex` is changed to null so that Element values are hidden.

Comment: it's working for showing one item .

but again i clicked that button not hide hiding that item.

Comment: Modified the answer. `(click)="clickedIndex == i? clickedIndex = null : clickedIndex = i"`

Comment: thank you i have some doubt can i get your mail mam

Comment: Contact in LinkedIn. You will find my link in the profile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199415/discussion-between-prabhakaran7-and-adrita-sharma).